# SQL Reporting Services 2005 - Date field based on a user entered date?

Tags: sql, datetime, reporting-services

I have a report in report services 2005 that has two date fields. The problem is that if users run this for a large section of time it uses too much resources on our server.

It is possible to only allow the end user to enter the start date and then the end date be auto populated/derived from this field (for example they enter the 1st of a month and this automatically change the end date to the last of a month.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Hide your end date parameter, edit the expression for the default value and do a dateadd function using the startdate parameter.